# Installing MySQL 32-bit on Ubuntu 22?

Tags: linux, mysql, 32bit-64bit, ubuntu-22.04

Simple question really, I'm trying to compile a 32-bit code-base on a 64-bit system (ubuntu 22).

Getting the error: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient: No such file or directory`

I know it's because the linker can't find the 32-bit mysqlclient library. However, upon searching I can't find the :i386 package for this Ubuntu version.

Do I need to manually download the MySQL source and compile it for 32-bit? Does anyone know of another (easier) alternative?

I think I had this issue a few years back on another distribution and ended up downloading the source code and compiling, but I'm sure there's a better way by now that will keep my distro "clean" by using packages?

Any help is appreciated!.

Comment: Everyone is phasing out 32-bit versions.  Why do you need 32-bit?  (There may have been a 16-bit version long ago.)

Comment: The Code-base I'm working on is originally from 1995, it's always been a 32-bit implementation. I've already ported parts to work on the more modern compiler(s), but the 64-bit byte types are really difficult/tedious to actually change (420,000 or so lines of code).

Comment: Can you show us a short example of the tedious-to-change code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've resolved the issue, here's how...

1. Installed the 32-bit environment for gcc and g++

   `sudo apt install gcc-multilib g++-multilib`
   `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev:i386 gcc:i386`
   `sudo apt-get install g++:i386`
2. Manually download and install the mysql-apt-config_0.8.23-1_all.deb from [the MySQL website.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/)
3. Installed the libmysqlclient21 package from that repository.
4. Created Soft link to the .so in the /usr/lib/mysql directory - `sudo ln -sf .././i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.21.2.30 libmysqlclient.so`
5. Discovered while it now linked, it wouldn't compile due to no dev-package for that version.
6. Download the Ubuntu18 packages (libmysqlclient21_8.0.30-1ubuntu18.04_i386.deb, mysql-community-client-plugins_8.0.30-1ubuntu18.04_i386.deb, libmysqlclient-dev_8.0.30-1ubuntu18.04_i386.deb), force-install these.
7. Recompiled, found a link error due to missing dependencies caused by the force install.
8. Downloaded the missing dependency (libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.20_i386.deb), installed (forced install not necessary).
9. `make clean, make` - Bingo!!! All working!

I had to make other code changes to the code-base prior to doing this, but this explains how you can get a 32-bit MySQL version working on Ubuntu 22.